# Cannot find module '../../image/image.jpg

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to put local image in img src but I get error like this:

> Cannot find module '../../image/image1.jpg'

I already tried

```
<img src={require(girls.Image)} alt="logo" height="100%" width="100%" />
```

```
const Allgirls = response.data.map((girls) =>
  <div id='fullUser'>
    <div id='User'>
      <div id='ImgLogo'>
        <img src={require(girls.Image)} alt="logo" height="100%" width="100%" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: You are getting an error because your image path is wrong.
Best: Add screenshot of your folder structure (and mention where you are calling it and where the file should exist.

Comment: Personally, I am also unable to comprehend what does this mean `require(girls.Image` (maybe because i haven't use it before)

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```
//import your image like below
import girl from "./assets/image/girl.png"; //relative path of your image

//use like this
<img src={girl} alt="logo" height="100%" width="100%" />
```

Comment: @nadav2150 did you get it?